# Linux Suspend wakes and goes black

Tags: kali-linux

Dell inspiron 14 5425 laptop goes to black screen after waking up from suspend (Debian based system - 5.17 kernel)

---

### System:
Kernel: 5.17.0-kali2-amd64 arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.3.0
Desktop: GNOME v: 41.2 tk: GTK v: 3.24.33 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 v: 42.0
Distro: Kali GNU/Linux 2022.2 base: Debian testing

:: I have problems with network and bluetooth Drivers ::

### Network:
Device-1: MEDIATEK MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Foxconn driver: mt7921e v: kernel pcie: speed: 5 GT/s lanes: 1
bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 14c3:7961 class-ID: 0280
IF: wlan0 state: down mac: 
Device-2: ASIX AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet type: USB driver: ax88179_178a
bus-ID: 2-2.4:4 chip-ID: 0b95:1790 class-ID: ff00 serial: 
IF: eth0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac:

### Bluetooth:
Device-1: Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
bus-ID: 3-3:2 chip-ID: 0489:e0c8 class-ID: e001 serial:

I'm still learning Linux and how it works,
I'm having issues with Network and bluetooth so i moved from 5.15 to 5.17 (5.16 causes freezing problem)
will this cause problems with suspend issue?

thanks in advance!!!